# Python script to DEMOSAIC a RCCB raw image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, demosaicing

I need a  Python script to DEMOSAIC a RCCB raw image . I've attached a sample image as well. [image]

any suggestions ? Thanks much . I hope I didn't create any obsolete question. I could understand the concept here , but not sure how do demosaic in python though :/

Comment: I have the same question. Have you been able to find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: yes i can share the answer in sometime

Comment: can you provide the solution